# PHPEXCEL gerando Notice: Undefined offset: 0 no arquivo Excel5.php

Tags: php, phpexcel

Estou tentando usar o PHPExcel para tentar importar aquivos .xls e convertê-los para php, para adicionar suas informações no banco de dados.

Porém, quando eu faço a importação de um arquivo .xls, me é gerado o seguinte Notice:

```
 Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp64\www\T-GET\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php
```

Porém os dados são extraídos normalmente do arquivo e adicionados no banco de dados de forma correta (pelo menos, até agora, eu acho). Só que me é retornado esse Notice toda vez que eu extraio uma linha desse aquivo .xls.

- Vou deixar o link do meu código PHP (no pastebin) e como eu faço a utilização do PHPExcel. https://pastebin.com/Rs8kiC1z
- O Notice apresentado parece ser de algum problema no arquivo do Excel5.php do PHPExcel.

**Abaixo tem o código, do arquivo Excel5.php, no qual o Notice está acusando anormalidade:**

```html
<?php
 
  //add style information
if (!$this->readDataOnly && $this->readEmptyCells) 
{
  $this->phpSheet->getCell($columnString . ($row + 1))->setXfIndex($this->mapCellXfIndex[$xfIndex]);    
}
            
?>
```

Alguém já passou por isso ?

**OBS:** Acabei de descobrir que essa library foi descontinuada desde 2015. Porém já estou com o código todo pronto. 2 dias fazendo. E é apenas um Notice. Eu poderia utilizar essa lib enquanto não achar outra.